# How can I rotate images and text every few seconds using CSS?

Tags: css

In a part of my website I would like to insert some images and a text under each image and I want that the images and texts rotate every few seconds. Is it possible to do using only CSS?

I have googled but I have only found solutions using Java Script or Flash or so. It is also possible using CSS3 @keyframes. But the problem is that IE and Opera do not support it. I'm looking for a pure CSS solution which is also compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using only css. There are some nice image galleries you can make out of CSS 3; however, as far as I know, they do not rotate automatically. Also since IE does not support most CSS 3 features, you will have to use javascript or flash if you need to support IE.

You may want to look into [jquery-image-slider-plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/02/jquery-image-slider-plugins.html) it is an article on http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/ which lists several nice image rotator plugins you may be interested in.

**Edit**:

For the page you linked in the comments. It uses javascript for the picture rotator. From what I have read this plugin seems to be from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/download.html. These are the two files I believe are used for it:

```
<script src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/drupal_38002/sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?lzqlgq" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/drupal_38002/sites/all/modules/views_jqfx_cycle/views_jqfx_cycle.js?lzqlgq" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at this site template? At the left bottom of the page you will see exactly what I'm looking for? Which  technics does it use?  http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38002.html

Comment: It is definitely javascript because when I disable javascript the whole template looks pretty bad. I will look into it more to see if I can give you any specifics.

Comment: It was not exactly what I was looking for (I wanted to do it with CSS as I mentioned in the question). But with your answer It's now clear what I should look for.

Answer (score 2):

Ya, I don't think you can stop it and start it again. It would definitely be a useful css feature.

Found this while I was looking into it: http://codepen.io/whootboy/pen/simple_css_3d_cubes/1

Not what you're looking for, but interesting how animation works with CSS

Comment: Ya, that looks pretty awesome.